# CAS-Server SSO - Proxying a valid scenario?

Tags: proxy, single-sign-on, cas

I'm currently trying to figure out wether or not the following scenario can be done with a CAS-Server setup:

- Suppose I got 3 Websites / -apps (A,B,C)
- All three are setup (via plugins) so that their login systems us the CAS-Server (already working fine)

To me this seems like rather basic CAS-stuff. Now two more advanced "problems":

- After I logged in to Website A and I open Website B I'm not already logged in but I do have to click "Login" again. I guess that's because CAS issues the login and cookies based the indidvidual service that called it and there's no way one can be auto-logged in to all sites connected to the CAS-login once you logged in to the first site?
- Is ticket-proxying a way to achieve this? As far as I understood, Proxying tickets would mean that (in my example) A on login also asks CAS for a proxy ticket for B which A would present to B upon calling something like a webservice at B. Which would rule out proxying for my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If you logged in into website A, you should be logged in into website B if they are connected to the same CAS server. Proxy is a mechanism to call web services from a web application, propagating the CAS identity.